# Access properties of navigation buttons in wxPython's wxWizard

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using the wxWizard widget in wxPython. Is there any way I could change the text of the next button on a page? Can i change the visibility of the navigation buttons on any page? Can I enable/disable the navigation buttons?

I tried looking for answers to these questions on the wxPython site but it doesn't seem to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wx.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD)` this will return a `wxWindow` object representing the Next button. Call methods on it. e.g.

`wx.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD).disable()` would disable the Next Button.